# Error while moving files in Android

Tags: android, file

I am using below code to move files in Android.

```
public static void moveFile(String inputPath, String inputFile, String outputPath, String absolutePath) {

    InputStream in = null;
    OutputStream out = null;

    try {

        //create output directory if it doesn't exist
        File dir = new File (outputPath);
        if (!dir.exists())
        {
            dir.mkdirs();
        }


        in = new FileInputStream(inputPath + inputFile);
        out = new FileOutputStream(outputPath + inputFile);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        in.close();
        in = null;

        // write the output file
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        out = null;

        // delete the original file
        new File(absolutePath).delete();


    }

    catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe1) {
        Log.e("Moving file not found", fnfe1.getMessage());
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("While Moving", e.getMessage());
    }
```

But most of times it shows me error as shown below:

> Moving file not found: /call_14-43-46_IN_+919737276726.amr (Read-only file system)

I have checked and the file which is to be moved is a normal file and not read only as it being recorded by a Call Recorder.
Please help.

Comment: Show how you call this function. Show the value of the parameters.

Comment: `dir.mkdirs();`. Check the return value as it might fail to create the dir. In that case display a toast to the user saying so. And return. Do not continue as it makes little sense trying to create a file in a directory that does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

In android you can't access the root (/) directly, it's mounted read-only. Check your path, you should not try to write to or read from / anyway.

Comment: I am not accessing the root path and both source as well as destination path are in external storage. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask yourself if your files should be available to the "outside" world, or are just needed by your program itself. Depending on that decision, you have a couple of options:

Instances of `Context` (for example Activity) know `openFileOutput`and `openFileInput`. Both return streams, and can be used without further permissions, but store files in places private to the app.

If you need the files to be available temporarily only, consider `Context.getCacheDir`. Or, the Java-way: `File.createTempFile`. Another method worth looking into is `Context.getExternalFilesDir`.

A side note: instead of glueing together your path manually I suggest using new `File("path", "dir").getAbsolutePath`